# java neko html, javax.xml.xpath

Tags: java, xpath, html-parser

Some help with this please:

```
   org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMParser dp = new DOMParser();
    dp.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div></div></body></html>")));
    Document d = dp.getDocument();
    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath x = xpf.newXPath();

    Node n = (Node)x.evaluate("//div",d,XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(n == null);
```

Any reason why n is null, thanks

Comment: What happens if you use upper-case `"//DIV"` for the XPath expression? I am not familiar with `org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMParser` but http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#uppercase suggests the parser might normalize names to upper-case names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the anserw, if you want to reach the div tag.

```
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\Test2\\res\\test.xml"));


        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0).getNodeName());
```

This gives me in the console --> div.

Hope it's helps,